# Windows laptop cannot detect battery

Tags: windows-7, battery, sony-vaio

I have this sony laptop about 6 years old. The battery lasts about half an hour or less. Now all of a sudden it cannot find the battery at all. The battery icon shows a red cross says `No battery is detected`. I unplug the battery and put it back in, it's just like nothing happened. Is it **completely** dead? I mean it would still be very useful even if it only holds like 5 or 10 minutes. At least I can move the computer from one room to another without shutting it down. What can I try?

Comment: What happens if you unplug the AC power? If the computer shuts down immediately, then, yes, the battery is COMPLETELY dead.

Comment: ha, haven't tried that yet. will try when work is done.

Answer (score 2):

> A laptop computer battery should last between two and four years, or
>   around 1,000 full charges. The total lifetime of battery life is
>   dependent on the type of battery your laptop has, how you use the
>   battery, how it's charge, and how well you take care of the battery. 
>   [(source)](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001236.htm)

If yours is 6 years old, and from what you described, it is highly likely it needs to be replaced.

Comment: My battery went the same way.  I agree with CharlieRB, buy a new battery.

Comment: the battery or the internal (in the laptop) circuit to charge it

Comment: This is referring to the battery itself. The internal circuit should last indefinitely, unless there is some sort of damage.